# How do I align a face for preprocessing

Tags: transform

I am trying to write a face aligner for as a preprocessing step before feeding my face into a neural network. I have found (using Python) the landmarks of a face via `dlib`'s implementation of [Vahid Kazemi and Josephine Sullivan's](http://www.csc.kth.se/~vahidk/papers/KazemiCVPR14.pdf) ensemble of regression trees to predict face landmark estimation. I have a tried a number of different kinds of transforms to no avail. This is my basic pipeline:

1. Find faces in image and crop image to only having the face :

   ```
   image = <some_image_with_one_face>
   face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
   detected_face = face_detector(image)
   w,h = 160 # so that facenet can use it 
   for face_rect in detected_face:

       # First crop the face
       left = face_rect.left()
       top = face_rect.top()
       right = face_rect.right()
       bottom = face_rect.bottom()

       new_face_rect = dlib.rectangle(0, 0, right-left, bottom-top)
       cropped_image = image[top:bottom, left:right, :].copy()

       # Get the the face's pose
       pose_landmarks = face_pose_predictor(cropped_image, new_face_rect)`
   ```
2. Find the landmarks (`get_landmark_points` returns a `68x2` array

   ```
   landmarks = get_landmark_points(pose_landmarks, N_LANDMARKS, dlib_point=False)
   ```
3. Define some `src` and `dst` points:

   ```
   top_of_nose = landmarks[27]
   left_eye = landmarks[36]
   right_eye = landmarks[45]
   bottom_lip = landmarks[57]

   src = [top_of_nose, left_eye, right_eye, bottom_lip]
   dst = [[np.int(0.5 * w), np.int(h/3)],\
          [np.int(0.3 * w), np.int(h / 3)],\
          [np.int(0.7 * w), np.int(h / 3)],\
          [np.int(0.5 * w), np.int(h * (2.0/3))]]
   ```
4. Estimate the transform and also transform the rest of the landmarks

   ```
   transformed_crop = cv2.warpAffine(cropped_image, transform, (w, h))

   # Get the transformed landmarks
   transformed_landmarks = np.reshape(cv2.transform(np.expand_dims(landmarks, 1),\
                           transform), (N_LANDMARKS, 2)).astype(np.float32)

   # Add the boundary points
   transformed_landmarks = np.append(transformed_landmarks, boundary_points, axis = 0)
   ```

Here is input and outputs of 2 inputs:
[image]

Although it kind of works, it isn't perfect as although the eyes and lip are of the same height in both images, their `x` position is different. I was wondering if there is some way to improve it, or am I using the wrong technique? It would be helpful if someone pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Kind of a huge topic (basically, head pose estimation). You might want to read the [publications](http://www.iiit.kit.edu/publikationen.php) of Sebastian Vater.

Comment: I've read up on some stuff and I'm implementing Delaunay Triangles to do the transform! Thanks for your links I'll read up on them